# setting maven archetype using eclipse GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/) to build a first spring application using hibernate, eclipse, tomcat, and MySQL.  At step 2 of the tutorial, the following instructions are given:

```
Create a quick project file structure with Maven command ‘mvn archetype:generate‘.
Convert it to Eclipse project (mvn eclipse:eclipse) and import it into Eclipse IDE.

E:\workspace>mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
Choose a number:  
(1/2/3....) 15: : 15
...
Define value for groupId: : com.mkyong.common
Define value for artifactId: : HibernateExample
Define value for version:  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for package:  com.mkyong.common: : com.mkyong.common
[INFO] OldArchetype created in dir: E:\workspace\HibernateExample
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use eclipse's GUI interface to do the same thing, without having to resort to the command line.  I have the m2e and m2e-wtp plugins installed with eclipse kepler and the springsource tool suite.

Can anyone show me how to use the eclipse GUI to Create a project file structure with Maven archetype, convert it to Eclipse project, and import it into Eclipse IDE?

When I type in File --> New Project... --> Maven Project , I get the following dialog box, which does not clearly show how to choose an archetype:

[image]

---

### EDIT:

After the great suggestion in an answer below, I still need to know which archetype to choose in eclipse for the specific tutorial to which I am linking above.  The clues that I see in the code are pick a number...15 , oldarchetype, and 1.0 SNAPSHOT but these clues do not mesh with the eclipse gui options.  Can anyone show me which archetype to choose from among the options that the eclipse gui gives?

Comment: Just a note:  1.0-SNAPSHOT is the version of the project you are creating and not the version of the archetype used to create it.

Comment: @Thierry Thank you for the insight.  Eclipse forced me to choose 0.0.1 SNAPSHOT. Does this make a difference? I guessed that choosing number 15 in the code from the tutorial above meant choosing the quickstart archetype, based on http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Version numbers in Maven are used for dependency management.  That way a Maven project can indicate what version (or a range of versions) that it needs for a dependency.  I think as far as the tutorial is concerned, the version number is does not make any difference, as you would never be deploying the created jar files to a shared location for other projects to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Next. You will get the archetype selection dialog.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for a fast and relevant response.  But which archetype do I choose for the tutorial to which I linked above?  The only indicator I have from the code above is 1.0-SNAPSHOT, but that is not listed as an option in my instance of eclipse, even when I check "include snapshot archetypes."

Comment: The example by mkyong uses the quickstart archetype and in the above list its the last one in the view (do not scroll down). This is auto selected by Eclipse